# How to Disable clicking the month name in Tempus Dominus Datetimepicker

Tags: bootstrap-4, datetimepicker, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

In the Tempus Dominus Datetimepicker, when clicking the month name, it goes to the list of months.

[image: Image1]  [image: IMage2]

I want to disable this. How shall it be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to disable the month select you can set [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to none for the picker-switch element:

> none
>
> The element is never the target of pointer events; however, pointer
> events may target its descendant elements if those descendants have
> pointer-events set to some other value. In these circumstances,
> pointer events will trigger event listeners on this parent element as
> appropriate on their way to/from the descendant during the event
> capture/bubble phases.

The snippet:

```js
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();


$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker('toggle');
```

```css
#datetimepicker1 .bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .datepicker-days table th.picker-switch {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.1.2/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.1.2/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1"/>
                    <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```